# grep word and retrieve the match and the following lines that start with a tab

Tags: bash, grep

I am collecting some terms that I use in my job in a file:

terms.txt

```
term 1
    here is the definition
    definition continues

other
    I will explain it here
    blablabla

random word
    etc
    etc
    blabla
```

I would like to grep for example "term" and pull the definition, the definition is in the next lines and start with a tab

I have tried to use grep -iA 3 termhere terms.txt but I would like to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a file is in paragraph mode I usually grep the paragraph in following way but by using Perl on a Linux system:

```
perl -n00 -e 'print if /term/' file.txt
```

Sample output is as follows:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ perl -n00 -e 'print if /term/' file.txt
term 1
    here is the definition
    definition continues
```

You can find more details about paragraph mode here - [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/computer/perltips.html](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/computer/perltips.html)